# Check if SQL job is running with VBScript

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

We have a daily SQL job that runs in the early hours of the morning.  The job runs for a different number of hours every day.  So I need a VBScript that I can run to check if the job is currently running or not.  I have a SQL query to do it but whenever I use it in a VBScript it returns nothing but when I use it in SQL it works perfectly and tells me that it is still running.  I have written many other VBScripts with SQL queries and they all worked perfectly.

```
USE msdb
SELECT
    job.name AS [Job Name],
    activity.run_requested_date AS [Run Date And Time],
    DATEDIFF( SECOND, activity.run_requested_date, GETDATE() ) AS [Elapsed]
FROM sysjobs_view job WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN sysjobactivity activity ON job.job_id = activity.job_id
LEFT JOIN syssessions sess ON sess.session_id = activity.session_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX( agent_start_date ) AS max_agent_start_date FROM syssessions WITH (NOLOCK)) sess_max
ON sess.agent_start_date = sess_max.max_agent_start_date
WHERE run_requested_date IS NOT NULL AND stop_execution_date IS NULL
```

I don't know that much about SQL but I assume this query is for a view instead of a table.  I don't even know the difference between a view and a table.  Can VBScript not query views?

---

**Edit**
I found another SQL query that give me exactly what I want as well.

```
SELECT sysjobs.name, sysjobactivity.run_requested_date
FROM sysjobactivity WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN sysjobs ON sysjobactivity.job_id = sysjobs.job_id
WHERE sysjobactivity.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sysjobactivity.stop_execution_date IS NULL
```

But now I get a different error which makes no sense to me.  VBScript code:

```
strSQLQuery = ""
strSQLQuery = strSQLQuery = "SELECT sysjobs.name, sysjobactivity.run_requested_date"
strSQLQuery = strSQLQuery = " FROM sysjobactivity WITH (NOLOCK)"
strSQLQuery = strSQLQuery = " INNER JOIN sysjobs ON sysjobactivity.job_id = sysjobs.job_id"
strSQLQuery = strSQLQuery = " WHERE sysjobactivity.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sysjobactivity.stop_execution_date IS NULL"

' SQL connection string
strSQLConn = "Driver={SQL Server};" & _
"Server=10.144.175.142;" & _
"Address=10.144.175.142,1433;" & _
"Database=msdb;" & _
"UID=username;" & _
"PWD=password;"

' Create database connection object
Set objConn = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )

' Connection properties
objConn.ConnectionTimeout = 800
objConn.CommandTimeout = 800
objConn.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"

' Open Connection to Database
objConn.Open strSQLConn

' Clear variables
strSQLConn = Empty

' Run the SQL query
Set objRS = objConn.Execute( strSQLQuery )

' Clear variables
strSQLQuery = Empty

' Check if any data was returned
If Not objRS.EOF Then
    MsgBox objRS.Fields( "name" ).Value
Else
    MsgBox "Not Running"
End If
```

The error I get now is incorrect syntax near "0" on line 30.  Line 30 is:

```
Set objRS = objConn.Execute( strSQLQuery )
```

So, that to me means there is something wrong with the SQL query but it runs perfectly fine in SQL itself.

Comment: Try to set msdb database as default in connection string and run your select without `USE msdb`, or use fully qualified names like `FROM msdb..sysjobs_view ...`, It may not work because when you execute USE msdb it finish execution and doesn't execute SELECT, because it should be done in separate batches.

Comment: What happens when you try to run this? Also, the VBScript code you use to run SQL would also be helpful.

Comment: If I run the first bit of SQL code in VBScript, it returns nothing.  I use the same method to run the code as I do in the code provided.

Comment: I don't know VB but `strSQLQuery = strSQLQuery = "SELECT sysjobs.name, sysjobactivity.run_requested_date"` shoudn't be `strSQLQuery = strSQLQuery + "SELECT sysjobs.name, sysjobactivity.run_requested_date"`?

Comment: I do not VBScript rather well, there is nothing wrong with that because I have the line right before it that reads

    strSQQuery = ""

Comment: @user3017424 I mean that you do `A = A = "text"` not `A = A + "text"` so in the end you get only `strSQLQuery = " WHERE ...` and syntax error during execution, am I right?

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't see that blunder.  That sorted out the problem.  Thanks again.  Stupid syntax errors again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `USE msdb` in your query when you execute it in VB instead:

1) In your connection string set `msdb` as default database

2) In your select use full names like:
    `msdb..sysjobs_view` instead of `sysjobs_view`

EDIT:

Also you have error when concatenating string:

`strSQLQuery = strSQLQuery = "SELECT sysjobs.name, sysjobactivity.run_requested_date"`

shoud be

`strSQLQuery = strSQLQuery & "SELECT sysjobs.name, sysjobactivity.run_requested_date"`

Otherwise you will get only last part of query and get syntax error during execution.

Comment: 1. I usually do this.
2. I will give this a try.

Comment: Tried option 2 while still specifying the database in the connection string but alas the first SQL query I provided still returns nothing.

Comment: @user3017424 I updated my answer, you can mark it as answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user lad2025 I found the problem.  My second bit of code / SQL query does the trick.  I just had a syntax error.

On a separate note, there seems to be a problem when reading views from VBScript.

Anyway solution is that I was using the following:

```
 strSQLQuery = strSQLQuery = "..."
```

That is supposed to be:

```
strSQLQuery = strSQLQuery & "..."
```